# How to get tweets from twitter using User streaming API with PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

Can someone please guide me in the right direction, its really overwhelming looking at all the related websites and codes.

I want to search for a phrase " i love you" and pull the matching tweets and display them on my browser.

Thanks